# Has Sklearn something like a visualization toolkit?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

Im using a Sklearn for my machine learning and my question is how can i see my process of my taining?
If i use Tensoflow i can see my loading process with Tensorboard. But does Sklearn have something like this?

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use matplotlib. There are plenty of tutorials of how to create a plot updating in real-time during your training.

However, personally I found these options pretty cumbersome. I instead chose to use the PyTorch interface to tensorboard.
That works like a charm and you can just pass in numpy loss values.
Here's how to get started: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html